# Use domain suffix in url parameter

Tags: php, url

I am trying to have a domain suffix like `.com` in my URL as parameter, like `www.abc.com/store/abc.com`. Where store takes to my page and `abc.com` should be my parameter. but when i try this "url not found".How can i get that?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```html
$url = "www.abc.com/store/abc.com";

$path_parts = pathinfo($url);
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
```

Comment: actually i m having issue to go to that page . browser assumes ".com" as some kind of domain (i think) and it gives url not found.

Answer (score 0):

You may want first to extract the Domain Part from the Page URL and then append it again to the Page URL like so:

```
<?php
    // THE GIVEN PAGE URL
    $pageURL    = "www.abc.com/store";  

    // EXTRACT THE DOMAIN FROM THE $page_url
    preg_match("#(www\.?)(.*)(\/.*)#", $pageURL, $matches);
    list(, , $domain, ,)  = $matches;

    // APPEND THE DOMAIN PART TO THE $pageURL VARIABLE TO GET WHAT YOU WANT.
    echo $pageURL . "/{$domain}";
```

Comment: i have the url as i want . issue is when i hit that url browser is giving not found url. I have some rewrite rules which takes anything after /store as a parameter. but in this case becuase of ".com" it gives not found error.

Comment: @nOmi     But does that route exist at all in the first place? i mean the *www.abc.com/store/abc.com* Route? If it doesn't, you will certainly get an Error although you can fake it in your htaccess file....

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempt to replace the dot character by his equivalent in [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) specification ?

`abc.com` => `abc%2Ecom`

Comment: i don't need encoded url. i need it like this url http://www.retailmenot.com/view/target.com

Comment: Your needed parameter is `target.com` or `retailmenot.com` ?